# Change only one axis of padding property maintaining the other using media query

Tags: css

I have set the following padding on a `div`:

```
padding: 14px 150px;
```

and I would like to change **only** left/right property but **not touch top/bottom padding** using media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
     #paddingDiv{
         padding: same as before (t/b)  change (l/r)
     }
}
```

The only thing that comes to my mind (I could not find anything similar to this, that is strange, so maybe I am looking for in the wrong way) **without changing top/bottom padding** is to put it like follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
     #paddingDiv{
         padding-left: 14px;
         padding-right: 14px;
     }
}
```

Take, for example, that the `div` has the following default `CSS` properties:

```
#paddingDiv{
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 14px 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cehvg9nn/).

**Note:** Of course, you can put `top/bottom` padding again but is not what I am looking for. I do not want to re-write the axis that has not to be modified. Like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
     #paddingDiv{
         padding: 14px 14px;
     }
}
```

**Note 2:** To avoid confusions, I have set the `top/bottom` padding the same as `left/right` on my example to make it clear (from a big padding put a very small padding) but suppose that `top/bottom` are different as `left/right`. In conclusion: **only** change `left/right` padding property maintaining `top/bottom` padding property.

Is it possible to put it in one line and without repeating the same value for `top/bottom` padding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the CSS Working group spec and the documentation that MDN provides, it appears that there is not a single line short cut for specifying **only** horizontal padding.

According to MDN,

> The padding property is a shorthand to avoid setting each side
>   separately (padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom, padding-left).

The available combinations of that short-hand are:

```
/* Apply to all four sides */
padding: 1em;

/* vertical | horizontal */
padding: 5% 10%;

/* top | horizontal | bottom */
padding: 1em 2em 2em; 

/* top | right | bottom | left */
padding: 2px 1em 0 1em;
```

Please see for reference:

[MDN's definition for padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

[The CSSWG current draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#the-padding-properties).

[The W3 Box model padding properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties).

Comment: As it seems that is impossible to get it, I give to you the bounty because you have the links to the documentation. I already knew all the possibilities that you provide before but anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the css spec for this, the current design is intended to be implemented using your second example.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
     padding-left: 14px;
     padding-right: 14px;
}
```

Comment: if you want to do a single line padding property than all 4 sides will have to be defined..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shorthand version of padding. This will put 0 padding on top and bottom, and 14px on the right and left.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
     padding:0 14px;
}
```

Comment: But as I put on my question I do not need to change `top/bottom` padding (I need to maintain the values that I have set before).

Comment: What are the styles that is rendering for the `div`

Comment: I edited my question. I expect now it will be more clear (I though it was clear enough before, sorry).

Comment: Haha, thank you! So if you want to keep the same padding through the different media queries, you should just specify the padding again. Put the padding at `16px`

Comment: I know I can do it putting again the same value for `top/bottom` but...Is not very reiterative? I am looking if there is a solution that **only** changes one axis. Not re-write the rest of axis that have not to be modified.

Comment: If you want it in one line, I think the only option is
`padding:14px 16px;`

Comment: I will wait if someone knows some way to do this. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is change:

```
padding: 14px 150px;
```

Where the first value is the top and bottom and the left and right is the second value. If what you want is for the left and right padding to be the same as top and bottom you can redefine it in your `@media` as:

```
padding: 14px;
```

or if you want the left and right padding gone you would write it something like:

```
padding: 14px 0;
```

It is worth mentioning that to change padding in a media query it NEEDS to be redefined and you simply can't get around rewriting it. But the most optimized way would be to define the new padding in a single line, depending on your particular selectors.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the only way around "re-writing" the padding that isn't changed would be to define them as individual properties.
`padding-left: 14px;
padding-right: 14px;`

Comment: I added a second note on my question to clarify doubts. What I am trying to achieve is to change **only** left/right padding and maintain top/bottom property without re-writing it. If possible.

Comment: Like I said, you can't change only left and right paddings without writing them individually as I mentioned in my first comment. May I ask why you are adverse to overriding the top and bottom padding? It literally causes no problems whatsoever.

Comment: If you want me to be totally honest, just I was curious. I never had heard nothing related to change one axis (and maintain the other) and I am curious about if there is a way to do it. I can see on the answers that there is not a way to do this (or at least not by the moment). Thanks anyway! :)